# Google map API dynamic lat/lng initial center not showing correct location

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-maps, local-storage

I am using local storage to store a lat/lng that is part of a product from another component. I get item lat/lng and set them to state, to use in maps.  When I step through everything it is the correct lat:32.735962/lng:-96.275256 for a location just outside Dallas TX, but when the map renders it is centered in the Gulf of Guinea. If I hard code the same lat/lng it renders the correct location.

```
import { Map, GoogleApiWrapper, Marker } from 'google-maps-react';
import '../css/googleMaps.css';




export class Maps extends React.Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        lat: '',
        lng: ''
    };
}


  componentDidMount(){
    const lat = localStorage.getItem('lat')
    const lng = localStorage.getItem('lng')
    this.setState({
      lat: lat,
      lng: lng
    })
  }

    logOut = () => {
        localStorage.removeItem('token');
        window.location = '/';
    };

    back = () => {
        localStorage.removeItem('lat')
        localStorage.removeItem('lng')
        window.location = '/patronmain';
    };

    render() {
      const mapStyles = {
        width: "60%",
        height: "60%",
      };
      return (
          <div>
                
                    <p className="lOut" onClick={() => this.logOut()}>Logout</p>
                    <p className="lOut" onClick={() => this.back()}>Back</p>
         
                <Map
                google={this.props.google}
                zoom={5}
                style={mapStyles}
                initialCenter={{lat: this.state.lat, lng: this.state.lng}}
                >
                   <Marker 
                    label='Made Here'
                    postion={{ lat: this.state.lat, lng: this.state.lng }} 
                    />
                </Map>
        </div>
      );
    }
  }



  export default GoogleApiWrapper({
    apiKey: ''
  })(Maps);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your map is being centered somewhere in the Gulf of Guinea because the value of your `initialCenter` came from your state which has a value of "". This means that the value of your `latLng` is "","" which the map considered as [0,0](https://www.google.com/maps/place/0%C2%B000%2700.0%22N+0%C2%B000%2700.0%22E/@1.6659638,-4.0446057,5.92z/data=!4m2!3m1!1s0x0:0x0) .

Please note that [initialCenter](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react#:%7E:text=%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0containerStyle%3D%7BcontainerStyle%7D-,initialCenter,-%3A%20Takes%20an%20object) parameter takes an object containing latitude and longitude coordinates. Sets the maps center upon loading.

To change the center of the map when changing the value of the state you need to use the [center](https://www.npmjs.com/package/google-maps-react#:%7E:text=%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%C2%A0%3E-,center,-%3A%20Takes%20an%20object) parameter which takes an object containing latitude and longitude coordinates. This is use if you want to re-render the map after the initial render.

Comment: So I made the change to center and the map moved to center on San Francisco. The latlng is saved correctly in local storage, and is set to state.

Comment: Can you provide an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) of your code that shows the value from localStorage? You can use [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/)

Comment: I think I have a good sscce on stackblitz https://react-hjtxt7.stackblitz.io

Comment: I checked your code and it seems that the issue is the typo in your center parameter. It should be small caps `center` and not `Center`. As for the marker, I can also see a typo in the parameter name where you use `postion` instead of `position`. Changing them to the correct parameter name will solve the problem. Here is a [sample code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7zucpu?file=src/components/googleMaps.jsx). Also, just a tip, remove your API key when giving sscce to StackOverflow to protect your API key from unwanted requests.

Comment: That worked! Thank you for your help, and the tip.